# How to set level Error to Warning on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

My project on xcode contains 3rd party libraries with source code. It always builds faild with showing error message :

> 'vsprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only.  Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use vsnprintf(3) instead.

I know that vsprintf is an unsafe function, but I try to take down the ERROR level to WARNING. But I don't know how to fix it on Xcode. Please help me.

Comment: If you look at the full and complete build log (not any possible abbreviated list) it should contain information about the warning option that caused the warning (which was probably turned into an error using `-Werror`). If you know the warning, you can disable it using either command-line arguments or compiler pragmas.

Comment: Or just remove -Werror option (to not lose the warning since it's still useful to know anyway that the function is deprecated and why).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know **why** but you can build your project with errors with checking the `Continue building after errors` in Xcode settings -> General Tap

[image: Settigns]

Comment: The problem is that the OP want to disable one specific error, possibly turning it into a warning only.